# Thread safety between static methods and a static block

Tags: java, multithreading, static, thread-safety

In a multi-threaded environment, is a class's static block guaranteed to finish before other static methods (in the same class) are called?

I don't mean in the event that the static block itself calls some other static method. In order to clarify, we can use the following code block.

Can an outside class start two threads, both of which call `OurClass.doSomething()`, and one them will begin executing before the static block finishes?

```
public class OurClass {

    static {
    // does something that takes a long time
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
    // can I be called before the block has finished?
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the static block itself calls any of the static methods?

Comment: It depends on. Please, give a specific code as example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can an outside class start two threads, both of which call
>   OurClass.doSomething(), and one them will begin executing before the
>   static block finishes?

No, that's impossible in a compliant implementation of Java.

See [section 12.4.1 of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> A class or interface type T **will be initialized** immediately before the
>   first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - **A static method declared by T is invoked.**
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).
> - T is a top level class (§7.6) and an assert statement (§14.10) lexically nested within T (§8.1.3) is executed.

And [section 12.4 just above this text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4) describes what it means to "initialize a class type T":

> Initialization of a class consists of **executing its static
>   initializers** and the initializers for static fields (class variables)
>   declared in the class.

---

For more details about the multi-threaded/memory model implications of class initialization, one needs to read section 12.4.2 ("[12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)).

In summary, this section explains that, whenever Java wants to use a particular class C, it needs to act *as if it acquired a synchronization lock *LC* on that class C*.

Then it needs to check whether the class is already initialized or not. It may only proceed with any action on that class when the class has been fully initialized. If it's not yet initialized, and it's not being initialized by another thread, then it needs to initialize the class at this point.

Specifically to your comment, section 12.4.2 states that once it has this synchronization lock on the class:

> If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress
>   for C by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for
>   initialization. Release LC and complete normally.

Comment: (first of all, thank you for the link to the right place in the spec).

However, this description seems to be contradicted by the case that  @Eran has written above, in which the static block calls a static method (which will indeed be executed before the static block finishes).

Comment: this is close, It looks like the gory details for this are in 12.4.2

Comment: @NathanHughes Yes, I just tried to summarize the 12.4.2 details

Comment: @Eyal Updated answer